# Backbonejs does not render data once deployed on a server?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a django + backbonejs application. The problem is that the data rendered by backbonejs after the api call is not rendered inside the data table on the live site. It works perfectly on my local machine.

My local machine shows the data 
[image]

The live site shows empty row for each record 
[image]

What can be the reason of this strange behavior?

```
 var PatientPageView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: ".st-content",
        initialize: function () {
            this.$dataTable = this.createDataTable();
            this.$inputTextField = this.$("#myInputTextField");
            this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.addObject);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.fetchAll);
            this.listenTo(app.vent, "patient:create", this.save);
            this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
        },
        events: {
            'click #addBtn': 'openDialog',
            'keyup #myInputTextField': 'searchTable',
            'click .viewPatient': 'viewPatient',
            'click .NotesIcon': 'viewNote',
            'click .paperclipIcon': 'viewAttachment',
            'click #export': 'export',
            'click #print': 'print'
        },
        save: function (object) {
            this.collection.add(object);
        },
        addObject: function (patient) {
            var view = new PatientItemView({model: patient});
            $('#patientsTable').DataTable().row.add(view.render().el).draw();
        },
        openDialog: function () {
            var view = new PatientAddSubView({model: new Patient.Model});
            view.open();
        },
        createDataTable: function () {
            return $('#patientsTable').DataTable({
                "aoColumns": [

                    null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, {"bSortable": false}, {"bSortable": false}
                ],
                "order": [[0, "asc"]]
            });
        },
        searchTable: function () {
            this.$dataTable.search(this.$inputTextField.val()).draw();
        },
        export: function (e) {
            view = new ExportPageView.MainView({
                content_type: 'patients'
            });
            view.open();
        },
        print: function (e) {
            window.print();
        },
        viewPatient: function (e) {
            var patient = this.collection.get(e.target.id)
            var editPatientSubView = new PatientEditSubView({
                model: patient, remover: PatientDeleteSubView,
                eventString: 'patient:deleted'
            });
            editPatientSubView.open();

        },
        viewNote: function (e) {
            var patient = this.collection.get(e.target.id)
            view = new NotePageView.MainView({
                collection: new Note.Collection,
                relatedTo: patient,
                content_type: 10
            });
            view.open();
        },
        viewAttachment: function (e) {
            var patient = this.collection.get(e.target.id)
            view = new AttachmentPageView.EditView({
                collection: new Attachment.Collection,
                relatedTo: patient,
                contentType: 10
            })
            view.open();
        },
        fetchAll: function () {
            this.collection.each(this.addObject);
        }
    });
```

The function 'addObject' renders this list.

The patient item view is simple

```
var PatientItemView = core.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: "tr",
        //template: _.template($('#patient-view-template').html()),
        template: _.template(ViewPatientTmpl)
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide your code, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: The first thing you could check is if you actually fetch the data from the server. You didn't post the models code. Check the url you're calling. Check if the retrieved data match your model.

Comment: Maybe you have CORS issues or something in the live site?Did you debug it?

Comment: The data is loaded after the api call but when the code tries to render it, the data disappears.

Comment: While debugging I found out that when the server goes behind a firewall the data stops rendering.